# How long does Safari's cache last?

Tags: macos, safari

I would like to know Safari's cache lifetime. In case it has limited duration, also how to extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Safari cache lasts for as long as the max-age header ([see section 14.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)) is set (by the server which is serving the file) for the specific file that is being cached, unless it is cleared manually. However, `max-age=0` caches the file until the file is modified (or the server tells the client the file is modified).

Comment: If understood well, it depends on the server, not the browser?

Comment: @Biotechnologist Yes